# RecyclerView with Retrofit/Okhttp image download get shuffled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, okhttp

I am using okhttp instead of Glide to download my image from server to recycler view because I need to use it in other activity. If it is downloading and I do fast scroll, the image of recycler view gets shuffled. IMHO it happens because of Asynchronous system of okhttp and `recycled` view is out of sync. How to solved it?

This is my adapter code :

```
class GalleryAdapter(private val context: Context, var list: ArrayList<Product>, val imageDirectory: File) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryViewHolderItem>() {
    var activityIsActive = true

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): GalleryViewHolderItem {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_gallery, parent, false)
        return GalleryViewHolderItem(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GalleryViewHolderItem?, position: Int) {
        holder?.let {
            val imageName = list[position].image.substringAfterLast("/")
            val imageFile = File(imageDirectory.path+"/"+imageName)
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(imageFile)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_lightgray)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_image_broken_lightgray)
                        .into(holder.ivProduct)
            } else {
                HttpClient(context).imageRetrofitClient
                        .downloadProductImage(list[position].image)
                        .enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                                t?.printStackTrace()
                                if (activityIsActive) {
                                    Glide.with(context)
                                            .load(R.drawable.ic_image_broken_lightgray)
                                            .into(holder.ivProduct)
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, response: Response<ResponseBody?>?) {
                                if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
                                    writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body()!!, imageFile)
                                    callMediaScanner(imageFile)
                                    if (activityIsActive) {
                                        Glide.with(context)
                                                .load(imageFile)
                                                .into(holder.ivProduct)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
            }

        }
    }

    private fun writeResponseBodyToDisk(body: ResponseBody, file: File) : Boolean {
        try {
            var inputStream: InputStream? = null
            var outputStream: OutputStream? = null

            try {
                val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)

                inputStream = body.byteStream()
                outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

                while (true) {
                    val read = inputStream!!.read(fileReader)

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                }

                outputStream.flush()

                return true
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                return false
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close()
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return false
        }

    }

    private fun callMediaScanner(file: File) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
        intent.data = Uri.fromFile(file)
        context.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}

class GalleryViewHolderItem(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val ivProduct = itemView.ivProduct
    val backDark = itemView.backDark
    val btUnselect = itemView.ivUnselect
    val tvName = itemView.tvName
    val tvPrice = itemView.tvPrice
}
```

Comment: You need a way to store what position of the list each request is loading and when you get onResponse check if that position is still visible. If it's not just don't load the image into the image view. The recycler view layout manager has getters for first and last visible positions.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov can you give me the code?